# Mongo query for comparing two indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Is there any alternative for this mongo query

```
db.test.findAndModify(
{
   query:{$where:"this.field1<this.field2"},
   update:{$inc:{field2:1}},
   sort:{field2:1}
});
```

because this query scanning all records and not taking the advantage of indexing.

Comment: what indexes do you actually have, and what type of data is in those fields?

Comment: { field1 : 1 }, { field2 : 1}

Comment: and the fields are numbers, or strings?

Comment: both fields are numbers only

Comment: and roughly what proportion of the records are returned by that query?

Comment: only single single record, actually it is not find(), but findAndModify().

Comment: sounds a little like an XY problem to me - it would be useful to have more detail, and also show the rest of the `.findAndModify()` query which is potentially updating `field1` and/or `field2` ?

Comment: OK, that's better, although the query is slightly unexpected, since it fails to return the same record being returned next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should create an additional field in your documents that is the difference between `field2` and `field1`, and then create an index on that.

In your `findAndModify()` query that increments `field2` (thereby increasing the difference) you should increment that `difference` field too:

```
db.test.findAndModify(
{
    query: {difference: {$gt: 0}},
    update: {$inc: {field2: 1, difference: 1}}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), the `$where` operator requires that the database processes the JavaScript expression or function for each document in the collection. This means that the expression `"this.field1<this.field2"` is treated as a JavaScript expression and therefore the the indices are not used.

You can't natively (without JavaScript) compare two fields in MongoDB using the `find` query, however, you can use the aggregation framework for this purpose. By using the `$match` operator you could do something similar to the snippet below:

```
db.data.aggregate([{
   $project : {
        equal : {
           $eq : ["$field1", "$field2"]  
       },
       doc : "$$ROOT"   // store the whole document, this is optional
   }
}, {
    $match : {
       equal : true   
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As **[`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/)** will load and eval in JavaScript and won't use any indexes, your best alternative would be to create an extra boolean field, say `"isField2GreaterThanField1"`, in your document schema that holds the boolean result `(field1 < field2)`.

To create the extra field, you would have to iterate the results from a **`find()`** operation and update the collection within the loop:

```
db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var comparison = (doc.field1 < doc.field2);
    db.test.update(
        { "_id": doc._id }, 
        {
            "$set": { 
                "isField2GreaterThanField1": comparison  
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Perfomance with the above update operation can be compromised if dealing with large collections, however using the **[Bulk API](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/Bulk/)** can streamline the updates for maximised efficiency by reducing the amount of update operations sent to the sever, sending once every 1000 queued operations:

```
var bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),   
    counter = 0;

db.test.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    var comparison = (doc.field1 < doc.field2);    
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { 
            "isField2GreaterThanField1": comparison 
        }
    });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 == 0) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-initialize every 1000 update statements
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.test.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

// Clean up queues
if (counter % 1000 != 0){
    bulk.execute();
}
```

Having created the new field, you can then create an index on it and query your documents as in

```
db.test.find({"isField2GreaterThanField1": true});
```